# Is it possible to fill a table (64 rows and 6 columns) with zeros and ones so that the conditions are met?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Is it possible to fill a table (64 rows and 6 columns) with zeros and ones so that the following conditions are met:

- All binary words of length 6 are written in the rows of the table;
- Not a single row in the table can be obtained from any higher row by replacing ones with zeros;

And does the 57th line contain the binary word 011100?

Every help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you count from $0$ to $63$ in binary and then cycle the list to put the desired entry in the desired place?  You may have to do this backwards to deal with $0$ adjacent to $63$. (Not an answer since I haven't thought it through.)

Comment: @EthanBolker: The table can't be cyclically permuted like that, because $000000$ must be the first element and $111111$ must be the last element.

Comment: @TonyK Of course. Thinko on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you list the binary numbers in order from $000000$ to $111111$, you get a list whose 57th entry is $111000$, which satisfies your conditions.

But now you can take this list and simply swap the first and fourth columns, to transform $111000$ into $011100$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: think about which of the entries whose relation to `011100` (the target) is forced. For example, you can obtain the target from `011101` by replacing the last one with a zero, so `011101` must be below the target. Conversely, `010100` must above the target, since it is made by replacing the middle $1$ in the target with a zero. What are the all other word whose position relative to the target is known? What does that tell you about the target's position?

Comment: I can count seven such words whose position must be below the target. This is compatible with the target being the 57th word.